# CNTK installation error in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cntk

AWS AMI

Deep Learning AMI with Source Code Ubuntu v5.0 (ami-5a77f822)

Installation procedure

pip3 install cntk-gpu

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cntk/libs/libCntk.Math-2.5.1.so: undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgesvd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by using the following commands.

`sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
sudo pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
sudo pip install cntk-gpu`

To check the versions of other libraries didn't change

`sudo pip3 freeze`

To check version of CUDA didn't change

`nvcc --version`

I am not an expert on virtual environments, maybe we can do the same there too at extra memory cost.